# JS order of execution

Tags: javascript

I am building a blackjack game in javascript. When the user clicks "hit me" a card is dealt and an image of the card is appended to the `current_hand` div. When a card puts the user over 21 points, the card is *not* appending to the div before the alert tells them they lost, so they can't see what their last card was. I'm having a hard time understanding why the alert is happening before the card is appended.

The code in question is at the very bottom in the dealCard function. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

```
<body onload="startGame()">

    <script type="text/javascript" src='cards.js' ></script>

    <button id="start" onclick="addPlayer()">Start a Game</button>
    <div id="current_hand"></div>
    <button id="hit" onclick="dealCard()">Hit Me!</button>

<script>
var sum = 0

function startGame() {
    deck = new DeckConstructor();
}

function addScore(rank) {
    var points;
    var result;
    if (rank == "k" || rank == "q" || rank == "j" || rank == "a") {
        points = 10;
    } else {
        points = Number(rank);
    }
    sum += points;
    if (sum == 21) {
        result = 'YOU WIN!';
    } if (sum > 21) {
        result = 'YOU LOSE';
    } else {
        result = sum;
    }
    return result;
}

function dealCard() {
    var result;
    var el = document.querySelector('div');
    player.dealCard();
    var suit = (player.hand[player.hand.length-1]['suit']);
    var rank = (player.hand[player.hand.length-1]['rank']);

    var src = suit[0]+rank
    el.innerHTML += '<img id='+src+' src="cards-png/'+src+'.png"</img>'; 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^this line does not seem to execute when player loses^^^^^^^^^^^
    result = addScore(rank) 

    if (result  == "YOU LOSE") {
        alert(result)            
        var el = document.querySelector('div');
        sum = 0;
        el.innerHTML = "";        
    }
    return player.hand;
}
</script>
</body>
```

I've tried moving things around, making a separate 'reset' function to call before the alert function, etc. When I comment out everything after `if (result == "YOU LOSE")` the card does display so I know it's functioning the way I want it to.

Comment: If might be working right, it's just that it is too fast for a player to see...

Comment: to @Alfabravo's point - if you wrap the alert in a `setTimeout()` does it show the card before the alert?

Comment: An image takes time to load. Have you tried just displaying text?

Comment: I also noticed some missing `;` semicolons in your snippet - not sure how that is affecting anything or if that was just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @Adam if i wrap the alert in settimeout(), it still alerts first but then it actually displays the card after dismissing the alert. Re: semi-colons, I just started js after working only with python so I'm not quite in the habit yet! I added all the missing ones and nothing changed so that wasn't the issue unfortunately

Comment: Most of the modern browser have now decoupled the rendering from the javascript thread, so even if the html is updated, the rendering has not yet occured, you might be in this case

Comment: I think it's going blank because `el.innerHTML = ""; ` is clearing the images out.

Comment: The div is not going blank, all the previous cards are still displayed. Only the very last card isn't appended. the div is cleared after the alert is dismissed.

Comment: @loopingz Sounds like i won't be able to accomplish this with an alert?

Comment: just for PoC i would try to inject the script tag with the alert along with the card to see if it is doing something

Answer (score 0):

Have the JS clear the hand at the start of a new game, not when the check for losing is done.  This is your culprit:

```
el.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code, I would try this for development purposes:

```js
    if (result  == "YOU LOSE") {
        console.log ("LOSE")         
        var el = document.querySelector('div');
        sum = 0;
        //el.innerHTML = "";        
    }
```

If the console logs LOSE and the image is displayed, you can be 100% sure that the call to alert() Is suspending the JS thread, causing your image to never be loaded. If this is the case, you will have to use something other than alert to show the YOU LOSE message.